# Where to report bug for wuapi.h in Windows 11?

Tags: c++, wuapi

I found a bug in Windows 11's [`ISystemInformation::get_RebootRequired()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-isysteminformation-get_rebootrequired). Where can I report it?

**Environment:**
Windows 11

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Setup a Windows 11 machine so that Windows updates are downloaded but a reboot is needed to complete installation.
2. Compile the code in appendix A for 32-bit and run it on the machine configured in step 1.

**Expected behavior:**
The application prints "-1" (VARIANT_TRUE).

**Observed behavior:**
The application prints "0" (VARIANT_FALSE).

**Appendix A:** Code sample

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wuapi.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlcomcli.h>


int IsWindowsUpdateRebootPending()
{
    VARIANT_BOOL isWindowsRebootPending = VARIANT_FALSE;
    std::string errorMessage;
    
    CComPtr<ISystemInformation> systemInformation(nullptr);
    HRESULT result = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemInformation, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&systemInformation));
    
    if (FAILED(result) || systemInformation == nullptr)
    {
        errorMessage = "CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemInformation) failed.";
    }
    else if (systemInformation->get_RebootRequired(&isWindowsRebootPending) != S_OK)
    {
        errorMessage = "get_RebootRequired failed.";
    }
    
    if (!errorMessage.empty())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(errorMessage);
    }

    return (int)isWindowsRebootPending;
}

int main()
{
    ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    try
    {
        std::cout << IsWindowsUpdateRebootPending() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Update 1:** @SimonMourier suggested another way to test ISystemInformation::get_RebootRequired() in the comments below. The observed behavior is the same.

Comment: As a general rule, don't compare for equality against the `true` variant of a boolean type. Windows has at least three boolean ABI types, and it is not uncommon for implementations to fumble things up. Try `return isWindowsRebootPending != VARIANT_FALSE;` instead and see if that changes things.

Comment: Although, the error mode sounds more like an issue with the WoW64 emulation. Since you're passing `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER`, you're getting a COM object created inside your process. Maybe that COM object cannot see outside the box and reports the virtualized 32-bit OS state. If that is true and the COM server indeed needs to run in the native host OS, you'd have to pass a different (combination of) [`CLSCTX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypesbase/ne-wtypesbase-clsctx) constants (I *think*).

Comment: You say the x86 version does not work, but you don't explain HOW it is not working. Is it reporting an error code? Is it crashing? You need to be more specific. Also, in addition to what IInspectable said, your failure handling is broken. Your are calling `CoUninitialize()` even if `CoInitializeEx()` fails, and you are calling `get_RebootRequired()` even if`CoCreateInstance()` fails

Comment: FWIW, you can easily test this method with CSCript.exe. Create a test.vbs file with this inside `Wscript.Echo CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.SystemInfo").RebootRequired` and compare the results from `\windows\system32\cscript.exe test.vbs` (64b) or `\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe test.vbs` (32b). You can check with your code results.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for the idea! I did what you suggested and the results match the ones of my code. Is there something I can do on my end, or is it a Windows 11 bug?
* Windows 10 machine with reboot pending
    * \windows\system32\cscript.exe test.vbs returns -1
    * \windows\syswow64\cscript.exe test.vbs returns -1
* Windows 11 machine with reboot pending
    * \windows\system32\cscript.exe test.vbs returns -1
    * \windows\syswow64\cscript.exe test.vbs returns 0 (should have returned -1)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. @RemyLebeau: get_RebootRequired() is not working properly in the sense that when compiled for x86 it sets IsWindowsRebootPending to 0 when the expected behavior should be to set it to -1 given the setup I explained. No error codes are shown nor crashes happen. When compiled for x64  get_RebootRequired() sets IsWindowsRebootPending to -1 as expected. I also tested on Windows 10 but this behavior only happens in Windows 11.

Comment: @GunnarTrollson then it definately sounds like a bug that you should report to Microsoft.

Comment: @GunnarTrollson Side note, just nitpicking your code: 1) `IsWindowsUpdateRebootPending()` should return `bool`, callers shouldn't care that your function is using COM. 2) `Co(Un)Init` calls really don't belong in a function, they should be done only during thread startup/cleanup instead. 3) `if (!FAILED(result))` -> `if (SUCCEEDED(result))` 4) `CoInit` returns `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE` if COM is already initialized, which is technically an error code but not a fatal error, so don't treat it as such. 5) `IID_ISystemInformation, (void**)&systemInformation` -> `IID_PPV_ARGS(&systemInformation)`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @RemyLebeau. I created a bug report through Feedback Hub (https://aka.ms/AAopswl). And also thanks for your comments on my code; I am new to Windows programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up submitting a ticket through Feedback Hub. Here is how I did it: Windows Start > Feedback hub > Sign In > Report a problem. After describing the problem I classified it as "Developer Platform, API Feedback".